# jquery numeric input onchange event not working

Tags: jquery

Using jquery and [texotela](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) inside my form, I have input fields that I want them to allow the user to enter only numric values.
so I added `$(".numericInput").numeric({ decimal: false, negative: false});` to them.

My problem is that my inputs also have a function called when the `onChange` event is triggered, but after inserting the plugin, the event is not triggered.

How can I allow the user to click only numbers and still have an `onChange` event for those inputs ?

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: FWIW - in HTML5, it's just `<input type="number"/>`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy What is FWIW?

Comment: @Vega For What It's Worth

Answer (score 1):

Looks like texotela is allready listening to onChange and maybe prevents additional handlers. I don't know what you're doing in your onChange but you could use [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) instead which is almost the same.

Blur will fire everytime the input field loses focus, change only if the text also changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good plugin to use for masking => https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

```
$(".numericInput").inputmask("integer");
```

it has a lot of predefined masks and you can use callbacks after a mask is successful or fails for additional criteria or validation.

The reason I like this plugin is the flexibility mentioned above when you have additional events as you mention.

Comment: I'm trying to use this plugin but the only problem that each input inside my form have diffrent maxlength number, and for some reason all the inputs become with the maxlength of the first input, even though i see in the source code that the maxlength is not change.. any idea why that happens? I'm using `$("#numeric").inputmask("integer");`..